# How I should set up my Django project tree in production

Tags: python, django, git, digital-ocean

I've moved my Django repo from development onto my remote DigitalOcean server ready for production. My question is - where do I put my apps, manage.py etc?

My current tree looks like this:

path: `/home/zorgan/project`

and the contents of the directory is: `env  manage.py  static app`

So I imported `app`, which is my repo, from Bitbucket. This contains my code including `manage.py` etc. Do I use this `manage.py` or do I use the `manage.py` in the outer folder? Do I remove the `app` directory altogethor and simply put it's contents (all my apps) inside `/home/zorgan/project` next to `env`, `static` etc?

Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the best layout for a Django project:

```
myproject/
manage.py
myproject/
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
    settings/
        __init__.py
        base.py
        dev.py
        prod.py
blog/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    managers.py
    views.py
    urls.py
    templates/
        blog/
            base.html
            list.html
            detail.html
    static/
       …
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_models.py
        test_managers.py
        test_views.py
users/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.py
    templates/
        users/
            base.html
            list.html
            detail.html
    static/
        …
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_models.py
        test_views.py
 static/
     css/
         …
     js/
         …
 templates/
     base.html
     index.html
 requirements/
     base.txt
     dev.txt
     test.txt
     prod.txt
```

I suggest you to read the original [post](https://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/)

Comment: Thanks, however I'm unsure about one thing: do I put me `env` (virtual environment) directory in the same folder as my `manage.py`?

Comment: This dependeds on your preference I suppose, usually in my local environment I have a separated folder that is external to the project folder where all my virtualenv live, however in production pc I prefer to put the env folder inside the project folder: for example yourproject/envfolder.